# CRC generated by crc32() from zlib is different from one generated using an online CRC generator

Tags: zlib, crc, crc32

I compiled ZLIB from https://github.com/madler/zlib and I want to use the CRC32 function.  I am running the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "zlib.h"

int main(void) {
    Bytef buffer[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};

    uLong crc = crc32(0L, Z_NULL, 0);
    crc = crc32(crc, buffer, 4);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When run that code, I get crc = 0xb63cfbcd

To understand how it work, I try to get the same value using http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html.   I tried many configuration but I wasn't able to get the same CRC

After analyzing the code, I see that crc32() do a pre-conditionning at the beginning of the function and a post-conditioning before the RETURN

```
    /* Pre-condition the CRC */
    crc = (~crc) & 0xffffffff;
```

...

```
    while (len) {
        len--;
        test = *buf;
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc_table[(crc ^ *buf++) & 0xff];
    }

    /* Return the CRC, post-conditioned. */
    return crc ^ 0xffffffff;
```

I removed the pre and post conditioning and now I can match the result of crc() with online version:

Result for both crc() and online version: 0x977824d1
Online configuration:
Input reflected: True
Output reflected: True
Polynomial: 0x04C11DB7
Initial value: 0
Final Xor value: 0
CRC Input Data (Bytes): 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04

I understand all the configuration but I don't understand the purpose of pre/post conditioning.  Is there someone to help me with that?

I expect CRC32() to give the same result as the online version

Answer (score 1):

Hit the "CRC-32" button, the first pre-defined entry, "CRC-32", put "0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04" in the data field, and hit "Calculate CRC!". Then it says:

> Result CRC value: 0xB63CFBCD

Doesn't get much simpler than that.

[image]